# Android 11 - Foreground service notification isn't visible

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-11

I have an android app that makes use of Foreground Services. My foreground service is supposed to display a notification.

**I have updated one of my devices to Android 11 and the foreground service's notification is not being displayed. The foreground notification works as expected and is visible on all previous versions.**

My code for starting a foreground service with a notification is as follows:

```
        String channelName = "MyChannel";

        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel("com.my.package", channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.my_layout);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.my_notification_id, R.drawable.my_icon);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.my_title, "Title");


        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "com.my.package");

        notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_image_icon)
                .setContentTitle("My Title")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(new MediaSessionCompat(context, MY_TAG).getSessionToken()))
                .setColor(0x169AB9)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setColorized(true);

   
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, MYMConstants.NOTIFICATION_GO_TO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE,
                new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notificationBuilder.setContent(remoteViews);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

        startForeground(10000, notification);
```

The foreground service is started as follows:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
        } else {
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
```

I searched for the official documentation on Android 11 and underlying changes to Foreground services, but I couldn't find anything. Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has changed the way how notifications are added to Foreground Service as part of Android 11.

I did find where the problem lies though. This piece of code above was causing the problem.

```
.setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(new MediaSessionCompat(context, MY_TAG).getSessionToken()))
```

Removing this fixed the issue.

To utilize setStyle(), we need to replace android.support.v4.media.app by androidx.media.app.